# pass string as url and load inside webView

Tags: java, string, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to send string as url from Fragment to Activity and load url inside webview inside activity. But I tried a lot and it is not working out.

Here is my Fragment code

```
intent.putExtra("url", "http://www.ekantipur.com/");
            startActivity(intent);
```

and my webview activity contains

```
package com.nepalpolice.nepalinews;
```

public class web extends AppCompatActivity {

```
WebView webview;
ProgressBar pbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");


    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    pbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, null, null, null, null);
}

public class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        webview.setVisibility((View.VISIBLE));

    }
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

}

It shows Progress bar and then blank white screen. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

Instead of this

```
 webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, null, null, null, null);
```

use like this

```
web.loadUrl(url);
```

and make sure, from the intent your getting the correct URL by printing in logs.

Answer (score 0):

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.loadUrl("http://appgeyser.com/");    
}

It is very simple. Use this for load url.
```

Comment: It is not what I want...i want to pass the individual string on each click of button and load the string on webview. I found the answer, I used   intent.putExtra("urlString", "http://neb.ntc.net.np/"); to pass my sting value and I used   String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("urlString"); to load inside webview.